# Transpose of a matrix containing transpose of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $M$ consisting of transpose of vectors $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}a^T&b^T\\c^T&d^T\end{bmatrix} $$

Would it be correct to assume that the transpose of matrix $M$ would be this?

$$ M^T = \begin{bmatrix}a^T&c^T\\b^T&d^T\end{bmatrix} $$

I'm also curious about 1x1 matrix
$$M2 = \begin{bmatrix}a^T\\\end{bmatrix}$$ Would the transpose of it be the same matrix? $$M2^T = M2 = \begin{bmatrix}a^T\\\end{bmatrix}$$

I generally know how to transpose matrices but am not completely sure if the same rules apply when having transpose of vectors inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is incorrect.  Instead, we have
$$
\pmatrix{a^T&b^T\\c^T&d^T}^T = \pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}.
$$
Keep in mind that the number of rows in $M^T$ needs to match the number of columns in $M$.

---

The operation that you have defined is sometimes called a "partial transpose".  It is often used in the context of quantum information theory.  For instance, the [Peres-Horodecki criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peres%E2%80%93Horodecki_criterion) uses this operation.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the reply! What about the case with 1x1 matrix?

Comment: @LennyWhite The matrix $[a^T]$ is the same as the matrix $a^T$.  Likewise, the transpose of $[a^T]$ is the same as the transpose of $a^T$, which is $a$.

Comment: I understand, thanks a lot! When multiplying matrix of a vector transpose with a vector we get $\begin{bmatrix}a^T\\\end{bmatrix}*b = a⋅b$. But what about transposed matrix of a vector transpose multiplied with a vector. Would this be correct? $\begin{bmatrix}a^T\\\end{bmatrix}^T*b = a*b$

Comment: @LennyWhite You transposed correctly, but keep in mind that the matrix multiplication $a*b$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix is defined as a block matrix $M=[M_{ij}]_{i,j}$, its transpose is $M^T=[M_{ji}^T]$.

So, with your notation, $M^T=\pmatrix{a & c \cr b & d}$, while $M_2^T=(a)$.

Comment: Sorry did you mean $M^T=\pmatrix{a & c \cr b & d}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, misprint...I've edited...